# How to convert byteArray to base64 for c#

Tags: c#, arrays, base64, byte

I have a two-index bytearray and I want to convert it to base64. But when I do, I realize it's broken. When I have Base64, I'm going to https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter and there's no picture. When I convert the ByteArray to base64, the images occur. Is there a way to translate this byteArray with 2 indices to base64 without being corrupted? Some of my code's downstairs. The `response.Base64` string is a value and I'm sending response to the client side. But I can't show it on the front because base64 is corrupt. I would appreciate your help.

On the 2nd path I tried, I get the `System.Collections.Generic.List'1 [System.String]` error. I would appreciate your help.

-`docByteArray` is in byte type

```
for(var i=0; i<docByteArray.Count; i++)
{
  response.Base64 += Convert.ToBase64String(docByteArray[i]);
}
```

The 2nd track I tried

```
List<String> listImageResult = new List<String>();
for(var i=0; i<docByteArray.count;i++)
{
  String a= Convert.ToBase64String(docByteArray[i]);
  listImageResult.Add(a)
} 
response.Base64 = listImageResult.ToString();

List<String> listImageResult = new List<String>();
```

In this code, base64s are in the form of an index. But when I want to merge, it doesn't. Is this something to do?

```
   for(var i=0; i<docByteArray.count;i++)
   {
  String a= Convert.ToBase64String(docByteArray[i]);
  listImageResult.Add(a)
  }
```

Comment: `listImageResult.ToString()` doesn't return the strings it contains. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: @Miamy How do I write my code using Stringbuilder? I'd like your help.

Comment: Can you provide us with the way you converted the image/picture to byte array?

Comment: @Hameed I updated my question. can you look again?

Comment: Still not much's changed, we still need to see how you obtained the `docByteArray` (how did you convert your image into your `docByteArray`).

Comment: Is it really too much to ask to check that your code compiles before posting a question? I mean my crystal ball tells me that you have a two dimensional array (which taken together is probably one picture) but that still leaves the question how you arrived at that (and there's all the possible formats that the website might or might not understand)

Answer (score 1):

If the `docByteArray` is the picture you want as a `byte array`, then using this:

```
String a = Convert.ToBase64String(docByteArray);
```

without the loop should work.

Comment: docByteArray is a byte type, so I get an error in the code you typed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not pretend on the full answer, it's just a quick example of  using `StringBuilder` - it's too hard to write and read a piece of code in comments.

```
StringBuilder listImageResult = new StringBuilder();
for(var i=0; i<docByteArray.count;i++)
{
  String a= Convert.ToBase64String(docByteArray[i]);
  listImageResult.Append(a);
} 
response.Base64 = listImageResult.ToString();
```

Comment: I wrote the codes you said, but again, the picture did not appear. Sorry, it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: As @Hameed said, it would be perfect to show how you obtain an array you have. Even for the simplest example (bmp) a data needs to contain not only a Pixels matrix, but a header too...

Comment: I meant way you walked to have your array. How does `docByteArray` filled? Or, maybe, you can provide us a sample of data, for example, on the https://pastebin.com/ .